# What is the best solution for communitate between apps in Tomcat container?

Tags: java, spring, http, tomcat, spring-integration

Assuming that, there are many ( more than 10 ) spring application in same Tomcat container and this apps need to communicate to each order within Tomcat. The payloads of messages are JSon objects or something similar in all case. My question is : What are the preferable solutions for this and why ? For example: Http REST, or JMS .. or what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a similar architecture. Our choose is jms. It's transactional and easy to use with a si. Rest is usual for frontend. Jms and WS for backend. But if you doesn't plan to growing. And all apps would in one appserver. You could use ejb.

Comment: Does JMS work between few Tomcats ? Right now, my applications are in some Tomcat, but we are going to plan that we use more than one container , and those will be on different virtual PC. And what is your suggestion, Where do I study spring JMS ? With Spring integration ?

Comment: Jms is distributed solutions. You may have one jms server. And you can access it from any places (only some restrictions with firewall) but its could solved. Si is very simple compared with different solutions and you have a full stack of spring power :)

Comment: Btw. SI provide SOA paradigm. If you need only communicate with some.components rmi is good choice.